# Can I use a .net control parent class to enable/disable it?

Tags: .net, winforms, multithreading, controls, parent-child

I need to write a delegate for a multi-threaded program that will enable/disable a variety of controls. It seems logical that using one handler for all controls would be the best choice, but I'm not even sure this is possible in .net and if so how to implement.

Comment: You could explain a little more, why the delegate? And is that the same as the handler?

Comment: When using a worker thread, one must invoke a delegate to update a UI control created in a another thread. I'd like to create a delegate that can handle all types of UI controls in so far as enabling disabling.

Comment: In that case assassin93's answer seems spot on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void SetControlsEnabled(bool enabled)
{
    // Make sure we're in the correct thread
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        // If not, run the method on the UI thread
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => SetControlsEnabled(enabled)));
        return;
    }

    // Put all control code here, e.g:
    // control1.Enabled = enabled;
    // control2.Enabled = enabled;

    // Alternatively, do a foreach(Control c in Controls) { ... }

}
```

Comment: Nice. What I was really looking for was the base class "control". Thanks.